# Why does port-based VirtualHost not work?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to serve up two different Django apps on two separate ports. I have app1 on port 80 and app2 on port 8080. So what I'm expecting is that when I put `example.com:80` into my browser, my request should get served up from app1, and when I put `example.com:8080` into my browser, my request should get served up from app2. However, sometimes it will serve up my request from the wrong app. Then, after a few refreshes, it will sometimes switch. What's more, sometimes it will serve up from the correct app and then, after a few refreshes, switch to the wrong one. I know this isn't due to caching on the browser's end because I've also tried sending requests with curl from the machine and I get the same behavior. I can't understand why I'm getting this unexpected, nondeterministic behavior.

Here is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                              
  ServerAlias *
  ServerPath /app1/
  WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /home/eyuelt/app1/app1/wsgi.py
  Alias /app1/static /home/eyuelt/app1/staticfiles

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app1/app1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app1/staticfiles>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerAlias *
  ServerPath /app2/
  WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /home/eyuelt/app2/app2/wsgi.py
  Alias /app2/static /home/eyuelt/app2/staticfiles

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app2/app2>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/eyuelt/app2/staticfiles>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be the problem:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

> **This is what you want:** You have multiple domains going to the same IP
>   and also want to serve multiple ports. By defining the ports in the
>   "NameVirtualHost" tag, you can allow this to work.
>
> **One or both of these could be the problem:** If you try using
>    without the NameVirtualHost name:port or you
>   try to use the Listen directive, your configuration will not work.

Server example:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I've tried using NameVirtualHost, and not only does it have the same behavior, but apache gives the following message: `NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release`